# Employe form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a employe form in wordpress.I have create a page and working there.Everything is working fine with validation too.But when i put validation on more than one textarea field it does not process form.Here is my php code but it is valid for one textarea.

```
    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
    $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
    $hasError = true;
    } else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
    $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
    } else {
    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
    }

}
```

and here is my html where i am showing validation

```
<li class="left margin-lef-00">
<label for="commentsText"><?php _e('Message:', 'mojothemes') ?></label><br />
<textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="8" cols="30" class="required requiredField">
<?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?>
</textarea>
<?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
<p><div class="error"><?php echo $commentError; ?></div></p>
<?php } ?>
</li>
```

here is second textarea php code

```
if(trim($_POST['adress']) === '') {
$adressError = 'Please enter your address.';
$hasError = true;
} else {
if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
$adress = stripslashes(trim($_POST['adress']));
} else {
$adress = trim($_POST['adress']);
}
}
```

and here is html code for second textarea with php validation

```
<li class="left margin-top-15">
<label for="Address"><?php _e('Address :', 'mojothemes') ?></label><br />
<textarea name="Address" id="Address" rows="8" cols="30">
<?php if(isset($_POST['adress'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['adress']); } else { echo $_POST['adress']; } } ?>
</textarea>
<?php if($AdressError != '') { ?>
<p><div class="error"><?php echo $AdressError; ?></div></p>
<?php } ?>
</li>
```

But when i change values for another textarea it conflict with form and it does not submit.Any kind help please?

Comment: I only see one textarea in there. When you add the second make sure that 1) the name value is different than the other and two, it is properly asked within each IF.

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes friend i have other textarea with different values.

Comment: Well from the looks of your PHP and HTML you are only validating one of them.

Comment: I have updated my question with all code friend.

Comment: Is the typo still on the actual code or not? On the PHP you have if $_['adress'] but on the form you have name = "aDdress". Note the D missing on the PHP.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `it does not process form` means what? does it show any error? does the screen freezes?

Comment: yes 'D' was missing friend.Actually i am not php coder.I just design :). Thanks